# SparkSQL sum each row with the nearest item preceding

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe which look like the following.

```
+-------+---------+-----+-------------------+
|product| location|  num|                 ts|
+-------+---------+-----+-------------------+
|      1|        A|    3|2024-01-31 04:28:27|
|      1|        B|   12|2024-01-31 04:28:27|
|      1|        C|   19|2024-01-31 04:28:27|
|      1|        D|    1|2024-01-31 04:28:27|
|      1|        E|    4|2024-01-31 04:28:27|
|      1|        D|    2|2024-02-02 04:30:08|
|      1|        A|    4|2024-02-02 04:30:08|
|      1|        C|   20|2024-02-02 04:30:08|
|      1|        E|    1|2024-02-02 04:30:08|
|      1|        F|   20|2024-02-02 04:30:08|
|      1|        E|    2|2024-02-03 04:32:39|
|      1|        D|    5|2024-02-03 04:32:39|
|      1|        A|    3|2024-02-03 04:32:39|
+-------+---------+-----+-------------------+
```

Then I want to sum the product total of all visible location from the nearest time.
I have try multiple ways of windowing but the nearest solution is only get the sum of product total with the same timestamp but **missing out other location from nearest previous timestamp**.

Here is an expected result, it should be calculate like below.

```
+-------+---------+-----+-------------------+-------+
|product| location|  num|                 ts|  total|
+-------+---------+-----+-------------------+-------+
|      1|        A|    3|2024-01-31 04:28:27|     39| --> A(3) + B(12) + C(19) + D(1) + E(4)
|      1|        B|   12|2024-01-31 04:28:27|     39| --> A(3) + B(12) + C(19) + D(1) + E(4)
|      1|        C|   19|2024-01-31 04:28:27|     39| --> A(3) + B(12) + C(19) + D(1) + E(4)
|      1|        D|    1|2024-01-31 04:28:27|     39| --> A(3) + B(12) + C(19) + D(1) + E(4)
|      1|        E|    4|2024-01-31 04:28:27|     39| --> A(3) + B(12) + C(19) + D(1) + E(4)
|      1|        D|    2|2024-02-02 04:30:08|     59| --> A(4) + B(12) + C(20) + D(2) + E(1) + F(20)
|      1|        A|    4|2024-02-02 04:30:08|     59| --> A(4) + B(12) + C(20) + D(2) + E(1) + F(20)
|      1|        C|   20|2024-02-02 04:30:08|     59| --> A(4) + B(12) + C(20) + D(2) + E(1) + F(20)
|      1|        E|    1|2024-02-02 04:30:08|     59| --> A(4) + B(12) + C(20) + D(2) + E(1) + F(20)
|      1|        F|   20|2024-02-02 04:30:08|     59| --> A(4) + B(12) + C(20) + D(2) + E(1) + F(20)
|      1|        E|    2|2024-02-03 04:32:39|     62| --> A(3) + B(12) + C(20) + D(5) + E(2) + F(20)
|      1|        D|    5|2024-02-03 04:32:39|     62| --> A(3) + B(12) + C(20) + D(5) + E(2) + F(20)
|      1|        A|    3|2024-02-03 04:32:39|     62| --> A(3) + B(12) + C(20) + D(5) + E(2) + F(20)
+-------+---------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

Is there a way to write SparkSQL or Pyspark to achieved this?

Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this solution:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from datetime import datetime

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark_playground").getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 'A', 3, datetime(2024, 1, 31, 4, 28, 27)),
    (1, 'B', 12, datetime(2024, 1, 31, 4, 28, 27)),
    (1, 'C', 19, datetime(2024, 1, 31, 4, 28, 27)),
    (1, 'D', 1, datetime(2024, 1, 31, 4, 28, 27)),
    (1, 'E', 4, datetime(2024, 1, 31, 4, 28, 27)),
    (1, 'D', 2, datetime(2024, 2, 2, 4, 30, 8)),
    (1, 'A', 4, datetime(2024, 2, 2, 4, 30, 8)),
    (1, 'C', 20, datetime(2024, 2, 2, 4, 30, 8)),
    (1, 'E', 1, datetime(2024, 2, 2, 4, 30, 8)),
    (1, 'F', 20, datetime(2024, 2, 2, 4, 30, 8)),
    (1, 'E', 2, datetime(2024, 2, 3, 4, 32, 39)),
    (1, 'D', 5, datetime(2024, 2, 3, 4, 32, 39)),
    (1, 'A', 3, datetime(2024, 2, 3, 4, 32, 39)),
], ['product', 'location', 'num', 'ts'])

df_with_content_array = (
    df
    .withColumn('content_struct', f.struct('location', 'num', 'ts'))
    .withColumn('content_array', f.collect_list('content_struct').over(Window.partitionBy('product').orderBy('ts').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)))
    .withColumn('content_array_size', f.size('content_array'))
    .withColumn('largest_content_array', f.max('content_array_size').over(Window.partitionBy('product', 'ts')))
    .where(f.col('content_array_size') == f.col('largest_content_array'))
)

df = (
    df.alias('original')
    .join(df_with_content_array.alias('aggregated'), ['product', 'ts'], 'inner')
    .select('original.*', 'aggregated.content_array')
    .withColumn('distinct_locations', f.array_distinct('content_array.location'))
    .withColumn('content_distance', f.expr('transform(distinct_locations, x -> transform(filter(content_array, y -> y.location = x), z -> array(abs(cast(z.ts - ts as int)), z.num)))'))
    .withColumn('closest_num', f.expr('transform(transform(content_distance, x -> filter(x, y -> y[0] = array_min(transform(x, z -> z[0])))[0]), t -> t[1])'))
    .withColumn('sum_closest_num', f.expr('aggregate(closest_num, cast(0 as double), (acc, x) -> acc + x)'))
    .select('product', 'location', 'num', 'ts', 'closest_num', 'sum_closest_num')
)

df.show(truncate=False)
```

and the output is:

```
+-------+--------+---+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+
|product|location|num|ts                 |closest_num          |sum_closest_num|
+-------+--------+---+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+
|1      |A       |3  |2024-01-31 04:28:27|[3, 12, 19, 1, 4]    |39.0           |
|1      |B       |12 |2024-01-31 04:28:27|[3, 12, 19, 1, 4]    |39.0           |
|1      |C       |19 |2024-01-31 04:28:27|[3, 12, 19, 1, 4]    |39.0           |
|1      |D       |1  |2024-01-31 04:28:27|[3, 12, 19, 1, 4]    |39.0           |
|1      |E       |4  |2024-01-31 04:28:27|[3, 12, 19, 1, 4]    |39.0           |
|1      |D       |2  |2024-02-02 04:30:08|[4, 12, 20, 2, 1, 20]|59.0           |
|1      |A       |4  |2024-02-02 04:30:08|[4, 12, 20, 2, 1, 20]|59.0           |
|1      |C       |20 |2024-02-02 04:30:08|[4, 12, 20, 2, 1, 20]|59.0           |
|1      |E       |1  |2024-02-02 04:30:08|[4, 12, 20, 2, 1, 20]|59.0           |
|1      |F       |20 |2024-02-02 04:30:08|[4, 12, 20, 2, 1, 20]|59.0           |
|1      |E       |2  |2024-02-03 04:32:39|[3, 12, 20, 5, 2, 20]|62.0           |
|1      |D       |5  |2024-02-03 04:32:39|[3, 12, 20, 5, 2, 20]|62.0           |
|1      |A       |3  |2024-02-03 04:32:39|[3, 12, 20, 5, 2, 20]|62.0           |
+-------+--------+---+-------------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

My colleague and I found a different approach that we think is going to be more efficient:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from datetime import datetime

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark_playground").getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 'A', 3, datetime(2024, 1, 31, 4, 28, 27)),
    (1, 'B', 12, datetime(2024, 1, 31, 4, 28, 27)),
    (1, 'C', 19, datetime(2024, 1, 31, 4, 28, 27)),
    (1, 'D', 1, datetime(2024, 1, 31, 4, 28, 27)),
    (1, 'E', 4, datetime(2024, 1, 31, 4, 28, 27)),
    (1, 'D', 2, datetime(2024, 2, 2, 4, 30, 8)),
    (1, 'A', 4, datetime(2024, 2, 2, 4, 30, 8)),
    (1, 'C', 20, datetime(2024, 2, 2, 4, 30, 8)),
    (1, 'E', 1, datetime(2024, 2, 2, 4, 30, 8)),
    (1, 'F', 20, datetime(2024, 2, 2, 4, 30, 8)),
    (1, 'E', 2, datetime(2024, 2, 3, 4, 32, 39)),
    (1, 'D', 5, datetime(2024, 2, 3, 4, 32, 39)),
    (1, 'A', 3, datetime(2024, 2, 3, 4, 32, 39)),
], ['product', 'location', 'num', 'ts'])


df_pivoted = (
    df
    .groupBy('product', 'ts')
    .pivot('location')
    .agg(f.first('num'))
)
locations = set(df_pivoted.columns) - {'product', 'ts'} 
for location in locations:
    df_pivoted = df_pivoted.withColumn(location, f.last(location, True).over(Window.partitionBy('product').orderBy(f.col('ts')).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)))
df_pivoted = (
    df_pivoted
    .withColumn('total', f.expr('+'.join([f'coalesce({location}, 0)' for location in locations])))
)
output = (
    df
    .join(df_pivoted, ['product', 'ts'], 'inner')
    .select(df['*'], df_pivoted.total.alias('total'))
)

output.show()
```

and the output is:

```
+-------+--------+---+-------------------+-----+                                
|product|location|num|                 ts|total|
+-------+--------+---+-------------------+-----+
|      1|       A|  3|2024-01-31 04:28:27|   39|
|      1|       B| 12|2024-01-31 04:28:27|   39|
|      1|       C| 19|2024-01-31 04:28:27|   39|
|      1|       D|  1|2024-01-31 04:28:27|   39|
|      1|       E|  4|2024-01-31 04:28:27|   39|
|      1|       D|  2|2024-02-02 04:30:08|   59|
|      1|       A|  4|2024-02-02 04:30:08|   59|
|      1|       C| 20|2024-02-02 04:30:08|   59|
|      1|       E|  1|2024-02-02 04:30:08|   59|
|      1|       F| 20|2024-02-02 04:30:08|   59|
|      1|       E|  2|2024-02-03 04:32:39|   62|
|      1|       D|  5|2024-02-03 04:32:39|   62|
|      1|       A|  3|2024-02-03 04:32:39|   62|
+-------+--------+---+-------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you save my day!! I have applied solution to the real dataset and it's now working fine!! Only the downside is due to the calculation seem a bit more complex then the query took much long time. 3M rows data, running in 6 workers, 4core 30GiB each, took around 9-10 hours.

Comment: You're right... It is computationally vary expensive. Meanwhile have you checked for data skew on the worker nodes?

Comment: @PraiwanN. Check out the new solution and let me know how it works.